# How to delete unused dropdown values, those unused by any product, on Magento 2.3.4, using the recommended API

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, magento2.3.4

I'm trying to delete unused dropdown options, the values that are not used by any product.

So what is the proper way to delete all unused dropdown options? What APIs should I use for this?

Here is a picture of where these options are managed in the backed, to help clarify which ones I'm talking about specifically.

[image: Manage Options]

Comment: Do you want to remove values from the `catalog_product_entity_***` tables or `eav_attribute_***` tables.? It would be good if you provide tables from which you want to remove values.

Comment: I need to remove all the unused dropdown values, have no idea where or how, or even what they are called

Comment: Wait, are they considered "Options"?

Comment: How you will describe exactly as drop-downs? do you have backend screenshot, only for attribute type?

Comment: Options or Options labels?

Comment: @MageSoftech, OK, I attached an image of where in the backend I'm talking about. I also rewrite some of the question and title, to help clarify better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on a similar requirement(slightly different) and created a console command to achieve this. Here is the code according to your needs:

> *php bin/magento rlt:delete-attribute-options --attributeCode=**color***

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="deleteProductOptions" xsi:type="object">
                    RLTSquare\DeleteUnusedOptions\Console\DeleteAttributeOptions
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**DeleteAttributeOptions.php**

```
<?php

namespace RLTSquare\DeleteUnusedOptions\Console;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion;

/**
 * Class DeleteAttributeOptions
 * @package RLTSquare\DeleteUnusedOptions\Console
 */
class DeleteAttributeOptions extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;
    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resourceConnection;
    /**
     * @var Attribute
     */
    private $eavAttribute;

    /**
     * DeleteAttributeOptions constructor.
     * @param State $state
     * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
     * @param Attribute $eavAttribute
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param string|null $name
     */
    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        Attribute $eavAttribute,
        Registry $registry,
        ?string $name = null
    ) {
        $this->state = $state;
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('rlt:delete-attribute-options');
        $this->setDescription('Delete Unused attribute options.');

        $this->addOption(
            'attributeCode',
            null,
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'Attribute code of attribute whose options you want to delete.'
        );

        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int|null|void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if (!$input->getOption('attributeCode')) {
            $output->writeln('Please specify attribute code in the command using --atributeCode argument.');
            return;
        }
        try {
            $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
            $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $exception) {
        }
        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
        $question = new ConfirmationQuestion(
            'Are you sure to delete attribute options? [y/N]',
            false
        );
        if ($helper->ask($input, $output, $question)) {
            $finalConfirmation = new ConfirmationQuestion(
                'This will delete unused attribute option for the attribute you specified. Are you 100% sure about it? [y/N]',
                false
            );
            if ($helper->ask($input, $output, $finalConfirmation)) {
                $this->deleteEntities($input, $output);
            } else {
                $output->writeln('Nothing deleted.');
            }
        } else {
            $output->writeln('Nothing deleted.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int
     */
    private function deleteAttributeOptions($code, $output)
    {
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $attrId = $this->eavAttribute->getIdByCode(ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $code);

        //fetching all options related to specified attribute
        $eavTableName = $connection->getTableName('eav_attribute_option');
        $selectOne = $connection->select()->from(
            ['eavAtt' => $eavTableName],
            ['option_id']
        )->where('attribute_id IN(?)', $attrId);
        $options = $selectOne->query()->fetchAll();
        $options = array_column($options, 'option_id');

        //fetching options that are assigned to product for that attribute
        $prodTableName = $connection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int');
        $selectTwo = $connection->select()->from(
            ['catPrd' => $prodTableName],
            ['value']
        )->where('attribute_id IN(?)', $attrId);
        $usedOptions = $selectTwo->query()->fetchAll();
        $usedOptions = array_column($usedOptions, 'value');

        //difference of both to get unused option ids which will be used for delete operation
        $notUsedOptions = array_diff($options, $usedOptions);
        $whereForDelete = ['option_id IN(?)' => $notUsedOptions];

        $output->writeln(
            'Found ' . count($notUsedOptions) . ' unused options for attribute code => ' . $code
        );
        return $connection->delete($eavTableName, $whereForDelete);
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function deleteEntities(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
    {
        $attrCode = $input->getOption('attributeCode');

        $output->writeln('Deleting Unused Attribute options.');
        $this->deleteAttributeOptions($attrCode, $output);
        $output->writeln('Deleted unused attribute options.');
    }
}
```

**Remember to take database backup just to be on safe side.**

Here is the bitbucket repo link for [module](https://bitbucket.org/omairkhalidrltsquare/deleteunusedoptions).

Answer (score 1):

You could try running this query in your database

```
SELECT
  eao.attribute_id,
  ea.attribute_code,
  eaov.value_id,
  eaov.value
FROM eav_attribute_option AS eao
  INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON eao.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS eaov ON eaov.option_id = eao.option_id
WHERE eao.option_id NOT IN (
  SELECT value
  FROM catalog_product_entity_int
  WHERE attribute_id = eao.attribute_id
) AND  ea.attribute_code = 'your_attribute_code';
```

It will lists options of **your_attribute_code** is not used by any product

Review the list option before deleting them

I hope it works well for you